# Spark Structured Streaming: StructField(..., ..., False) always returns `nullable=true` instead of `nullable=false`

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark Structured Streaming (3.2.1) with Kafka.

I'm trying to simply read JSON from Kafka using a defined schema.

My problem is that in defined schema I got non-nullable field that is ignored when I read messages from Kafka. I use the `from_json` functions that seems to ignore that some fields can't be `null`.

Here is my code example:

```
val schemaTest = new StructType()
  .add("firstName", StringType)
  .add("lastName", StringType)
  .add("birthDate", LongType, nullable = false)

val loader =
    spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "BROKER:PORT")
    .option("subscribe", "TOPIC")
    .load()

val df = loader.
     selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
    .withColumn("value", from_json(col("value"), schemaTest))
    .select(col("value.*"))

df.printSchema()

val q = df.writeStream
  .format("console")
  .option("truncate","false")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

I got this when I'm printing the schema of `df` which is different of my `schemaTest`:

```
root
 |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- birthDate: long (nullable = true)
```

And received data are like that:

```
+---------+--------+----------+
|firstName|lastName|birthDate |
+---------+--------+----------+
|Toto     |Titi    |1643799912|
+---------+--------+----------+
|Tutu     |Tata    |null      |
+---------+--------+----------+
```

We also try to add option to change mode in `from_json` function from default one `PERMISSIVE` to others (`DROPMALFORMED`, `FAILFAST`) but in fact the second record that doesn't respect the defined schema is simply not considered as corrupted because the field `birthDate` is nullable..

Maybe I missed something but if it's not the case, I got following questions.

Do you know why the printSchema of `df` is not like my `schemaTest` ? (With non nullable field)

And also, how can I manage non-nullable value in my case ? I know that I can filter but I would like to know if there is an alternative using schema like it's supposed to work. And also, It's not quite simple to filter if I got a schema with lots of fields non-nullable.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually the intended behavior of `from_json` function. You can read the following from the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/15464e37a19ee99147550bab96d2674fb05d06df/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/jsonExpressions.scala#L533):

```scala
// The JSON input data might be missing certain fields. We force the nullability
// of the user-provided schema to avoid data corruptions. In particular, the parquet-mr encoder
// can generate incorrect files if values are missing in columns declared as non-nullable.
val nullableSchema = schema.asNullable

override def nullable: Boolean = true
```

If you have multiple fields which are mandatory then you can construct the filter expression from your `schemaTest` (or list of columns) and use it like this:

```scala
val filterExpr = schemaTest.fields
  .filter(!_.nullable)
  .map(f => col(f.name).isNotNull)
  .reduce(_ and _)

val df = loader
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .withColumn("value", from_json(col("value"), schemaTest))
  .select(col("value.*"))
  .filter(filterExpr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose a different way of doing :

```scala
 def isCorrupted(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val filterNullable = schemaTest
    .filter(e => !e.nullable)
    .map(_.name)

  filterNullable.foldLeft(df) { case ((accumulator), (columnName)) =>
      accumulator.withColumn("isCorrupted", when(col(columnName).isNull, 1).otherwise(0))
  } 
  .filter(col("isCorrupted") === lit(0)) 
  .drop(col("isCorrupted"))
  
}

val df = loader
  .selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING)")
  .withColumn("value", from_json(col("value"), schemaTest))
  .select(col("value.*"))
  .transform(isCorrupted)
```